# When Deleting a file the app does not update my ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with file names and when I long press a file name I delete it, but the ListView is not updating its contents after calling

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I populate the listview with the following:

```
    dirFiles = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.computergr.ats/files/"+"");
    File list[] = dirFiles.listFiles();
    if(list!=null)
    {
        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
        ListFiles.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I delete the file using the following:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Settings.this);
            alert.setTitle("WARNING..");
            alert.setMessage("Are you sure to delete file?");
            alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do your work here
                    String filename = ListFiles.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                    String WebFile = dirFiles + "/" + filename;
                    File file = new File(WebFile);
                    if(file.exists())
                    {
                        file.delete();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            alert.show();
            return true;
```

Comment: please post all code

Comment: remove your item from myList object postion and after this u update listview

Comment: How I remove item from MyList object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating the list you provide to the adapter. You deleted the item from the system but the array list of items need to be updated.

Update your block for deleting to update the `ArrayList` you provide and then call

```
 @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do your work here
                    String filename = ListFiles.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                    String WebFile = dirFiles + "/" + filename;
                    File file = new File(WebFile);
                    if(file.exists())
                    {
                        file.delete();
                        //This is the line your missing. ArrayAdapter 
                        //comes with a method to delete objects in it's array
                        //since your array uses the names of the files. 
                        //Pass the remove method the name of the file.
                        adapter.remove(File.getName());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

[ArrayAdater Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) 
[Android File Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should delete file in the adapter itself or in the container used for adapter, otherwise it will still be displayed.

Comment: As @Daniil said you have to clear the listview arraylsit of any other listitems and then update the notify adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file.exists())
{
file.delete();
myList.remove(postion)//After this u can run notifyDataSetChanged method 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
dialog.dismiss();
```